# Can't update old posts 3.5.2

Tags: posts, database, attachments, updates

**Background:** I'm working on a customers site that I haven't build myself. The site works pretty ok, when I got it the wp_header and wp_footer was missing and the javascript files were all linked to before the body tag was closed.

WordPress 3.5.2

**Issue:** There is this problem with old posts and printing the updated content. The content is printed in a foreach where the attached images of one posts should be displayed. For some reason the old content is stuck there. I can update the post, see the content of the post, but I cant see the new content on the specific place where I'm trying to display it.

The foreach results in a scrolling div that is moving back and forward with the images.

**I've tried:** Repairing the database, to disable all of the plugins, update WordPress and all the plugins.

**I don't have:** Access to edit the database.

I would really appreciate some help with this if possible. Been searching for a solution almost a whole day now.

**Code:**

```
$bottomSliderImages = get_posts(
    array(
         'numberposts' => -1,
         'post_parent' => 54,     
         'post_status' => 'inherit',
         'post_type' => 'attachment',
         'post_mime_type' => 'image',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
    )   
);

<?php foreach($bottomSliderImages as $img): ?>
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img->ID, '200,94'); 
      if ($img->post_excerpt): ?>
      <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $img->post_excerpt; ?>"><?php endif; ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img->post_title; ?>" />
<?php if ($img->post_excerpt): ?></a><?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `$img->post_excerpt` is your content. It is the attachment's caption field. You must change the images' captions attached to the post with the id `54` in order to see any changes , if I understood the question right.

ADD:
Also attach the images to the post.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for trying to help. I've tried to change the image caption but I still can't see the updated content. There's still the old one. I don't have any cache plugin so I don't understand how it can still be there.

Comment: Hi , I would need to make some debugging. If you feel that you can trust me your WP credentials , i will help you with this. Don't write them here as it is not safe.

Comment: Since it's not my site I can't give away any info about it. You don't have any other ideas without looking at it?

Comment: At least a link to the page/post so i can see what is it about. The function looks fine.

Comment: I've tried to remove things from the code, like the alt text and it works. But the images remains the same. And I cant figure out where they come from and why the images I've put in the post doesn't show. It's like the images are stuck on the site.

Comment: Sure, you got an email address?

Comment: toleabivol@yahoo.com

Comment: With Toleas help I realized that the problem was that the image had to be uploaded to that specific posts because so it became attached to the post.